How to get privileges from the Microsoft Dynamics Web API of the authenticated user?
We are using the Microsoft Dynamics Web API (HTTP) to integrate our application with our customers' Dynamics Sales CRM. The API is authenticated using OAuth.
We need to ensure that the user who authenticates has the necessary privileges to carry out all actions. So, we want to query the Web API to fetch the authenticated users privileges. How can that be done?
There is an API function called RetrieveUserPrivileges, but that requires a user ID, which we don't have. Is there any way, like with some other APIs, to request "my" privileges, i.e., the authenticated user's?

Could you use the WhoAmI request first to get their user ID? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/reference/whoami?view=dataverse-latest
